# Constructor in abstract and non-abstract classes

Tags: java

I have a GenericContainer class and a FIFOContainer class that extends the generic one. My problem appears when trying to use the takeout() method. It does not recognize that I hold values in my FIFOContainer ArrayList.
I suspect this has something to do with how I defined the constructors but for the life of me cannot figure it out how to solve it.

A solution I thought of is defining a getter in the GenericContainer class and passing the value in the FIFOContainer class but I feel like this should not be needed.

```
public abstract class GenericContainer implements IBag {

    private ArrayList<ISurprise> container;

    public GenericContainer() {
        this.container = new ArrayList<ISurprise>();
    }

    @Override
    public void put(ISurprise newSurprise) {
        this.container.add(newSurprise);
    }

    @Override
    public void put(IBag bagOfSurprises) {
        while (!bagOfSurprises.isEmpty()) {
            System.out.println(bagOfSurprises.size());
            this.container.add(bagOfSurprises.takeout());
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isEmpty() {
        if (this.container.size() > 0) {
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public int size() {
        if (isEmpty() == false) {
            return this.container.size();
        }
        return -1;
    }

}

public class FIFOContainer extends GenericContainer {

    private ArrayList<ISurprise> FIFOcontainer;

    public FIFOContainer() {
        super();
        this.FIFOcontainer = new ArrayList<ISurprise>();        

    }

    public ISurprise takeout() {
        if (isEmpty() == false) {
            this.FIFOcontainer.remove(0);
            ISurprise aux = this.FIFOcontainer.get(0);
            return aux;
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: You should follow the Java Naming Conventions: variable names and method names are written in camelCase. So `FIFOcontainer` violates these conventions.

Comment: Another hint: your size() method, that is really nonsensical. Again: there is **zero** value in that if statement. The GenericContainer size ... is the size of its container. You are writing a lot of code that is just *not* necessary. Worse: it is confusing, and thus allows for bugs to hide. as: no java collection can have a size of -1. Sizes go from 0 to whatever. They are NOT negative.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thing is: **fields** are not poylmorphic (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43407138/why-arent-java-fields-polymorphic) for example).

Your problem: basically your `isEmpty()` will use the container in the base class, and the other method will us the container in the subclass.

Yes, there are **two** containers in your class.

A better approach could be to (for example) do this in the base class GenericContainer:

```
protected abstract List<ISurprise> getContainer();
```

In other words: a subclass could provide its own container, and base methods as `isEmpty()` could use that one:

```
@Override
public final boolean isEmpty() {
    return getContainer().isEmpty();
}
```

To allow for more degrees of freedom, that method could also have a slightly different signature, such as `protected abstract Collection<ISurprise>` to be more flexible about the actual implementation.

( hint: I made the method final, as that is the whole idea of methods defined in an abstract base class: that subclasses do not overwrite them )

( and bonus hints: try to minimize the amount of code that you write. you don't do `someBool == true/false`, you don't need to do `getSize() == 0` when that list class already offers you an isEmpty() method )

Comment: Instead of overriding the isEmpty() method in the FIFOcontainer class, wouldn't if (getContainer().isEmpty() == false)  work just as well?

Comment: @BogdanBuzaianu please read carefully: my approach would be: the base class can call `getContainer()` to do its job, and the **child** classes would implement that. And again: when you already have a method that goes `boolean isEmpty()` on that collection itself, then putting an if statement around that and == false is nothing but **noise**. The result of base.isEmpty() is just that: getContainer.getEmpty(). No need for an if, no need for a comparison, no need to say == false, no need for a second return true.

Comment: This is where i get confused: I am defining the abstract method getContainer in the GenericContainer class. I am overriding it in the FIFOContainer class. But then I'm doing this in the GenericContainer isEmpty(): return getContainer.isEmpty();. Since the method is overriden in the child class, how should it work? Sorry, I am really trying to understand but OOP is pretty new for me

Comment: @BogdanBuzaianu The child class implements "getContainer()". Only that. The base class implements isEmpty(). And the child class doesn't touch isEmpty()!

Comment: Which means I do not need an ArrayList field in the base class anymore, since I can always call getContainer()?

Comment: @BogdanBuzaianu Exactly. That is one option. Of course, you could have a list in the base class, but then **only** in the base class. And then you would probably make that one protected. From a conceptual point of view, both options could work. It really depends on your exact requirements, and the underlying goal you intend to achieve. But please understand that SO is not a discussion forum. You ask a question, you get an answer. Coming back with more and more questions within comments isn't how things should go here.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't create new arraylist in `FIFOContianer`. you already have list from `GenericContainer`.
So right now, when you are calling `put` it adds item to the `container` list in the parent class. when calling `takeout` you are accessing **other** list (`FIFOcontainer`) which you created in the child class.

just remove `FIFOcontainer` and keep using `container`:

```java
 public ISurprise takeout() {
        if (isEmpty() == false) {
            this.container.remove(0);
            ISurprise aux = this.container.get(0);
            return aux;
        }
        return null;
    }
```

Comment: But the container field in GenericContainer is private. This would not work without a getter

Comment: you should change it to `protected`

Comment: @BogdanBuzaianu When the getter is *protected* then of course it can *get* you a private field of a superclass. But as I have written in my answer: that is the wrong way. I *might* make more sense for the subclasses to give access to "their" containers.

Comment: @GhostCat I agree you're answer is the better one, and it good to notice that it follows the Open-Closed principle